# obtener numero de hijo jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches tengo la siguiente lista:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li class="active">3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

desearia mediante jquery o javascript poder saber que numero de hijo es .active, en este caso es el hijo 3 pero como podria saberlo de manera automatica?.

e intentado con .lenght al padre ul pero solo me devuelve cuantos elementos hijo tengo

Comment: Pues ponlo en la pregunta, para que veamos como lo has hecho, pues combinando la propiedad [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) con un bucle que recorra los elementos y compruebe cual de ellos tiene esa clase ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Con [QuerySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) puedes acceder facilmente a todos los li .active
`document.querySelectorAll('ul > li.active');`

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li.active');

for (let elem of elements) {
  console.log(elem.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li class="active">3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: lo que yo deseo hacer es saber el numero de hijo que estoy seleccionando amigo :(